# Ajuda com digitação de usuário

Tags: c

Olá, estou fazendo um programa de selection sort em c, mas estou com dificuldades.
Como ou onde, e o que coloco para que o usuário digite o tamanho do array assim como seus elementos.

Tentei assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){ 
 int num[];
 int tam, l;
 int i, j, min, aux;
 printf("Digite o tamanho do array: ");
 scanf("%d", tam);
 printf("Digite o array: ");
 scanf("%d", num[]);
 for (i = 0; i < (tam-1); i++){
   min = i;
   for (j = (i+1); j < tam; j++) {
      if(num[j] < num[min]) {
         min = j;
      }
   }
   if (i != min) {
      aux = num[i];
      num[i] = num[min];
      num[min] = aux;
   }
   printf("\n");

 }
}
```

Mas quando digita algo já fecha o programa, alguém sabe como arrumar?

Comment: Porquê você tem que informar o array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você declarou o array mas não determinou o tamanho dele.

Se você vai decidir o tamanho dele em tempo de execução, é preciso alocar memória para ele. Uma solução é usar a função malloc. Ela faz parte do arquivo de cabeçalho

```
<stdlib.h>
```

Então certifique-se de incluí-lo no seu programa.

Primeiro declare um ponteiro

```
int *array;
```

Depois que você ler o tamanho dele, aloque as posições de memória:

```
array = (*int)malloc(tam*sizeof(int));
```

Assim seu ponteiro conterá *tam* elementos e você poderá indexar assim:

```
array[0] = 1;
```

Você tentou acessar uma posição que não existe na memória, por isso deu erro e o programa foi abortado.

Outra maneira é criar um array de tamanho grande e usar o que o usuário quiser. Mas é uma solução menos eficiente.

Outra coisa, seu scanf faltou o & na leitura da variável. A função precisa saber o endereço da variável tam e você precisa usar esse operador para tal &:

```
scanf("%d", &tam);
```

Dessa forma ele vai saber onde *tam* está na memória e vai salvar o valor lido dentro da variável.

A leitura dos elementos do array precisa ser feito de um por um, ou seja, use um laço de repetição para ler cada posição do seu array:

```
for(i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}
```

Comment: O *cast* no `malloc` é, quando muito, redundante, e pode esconder um erro que o compilador apanharia na ausência do *cast*.

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma alterada no seu **código** da uma olhada talvez te ajude.

```
int main()
{
    int *array;
    int tam = 0, num = 0;
    int i, j, min, aux;

    printf("Digite o tamanho do array: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &tam);

    array = (int *)malloc(tam*sizeof(int));

    printf("\nDigite o array: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < (tam - 1); i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (j = (i + 1); j < tam; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != min) 
        {
            aux = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = aux;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    getchar();
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o porquê tem que informar o array. Mais enfim,
espero que ajude.